# How to reload UIBarButtonItem in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationitem

My app is like a shopping cart. I have added one cart UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar.
In cart button I have added a badge at top.
Now my question is when I add an Item on cart How to update badge on button without navigation or when I delete an item from cart badge would be update.
**Is it possible to reload navigation bar without navigation?**

Comment: https://github.com/matteogobbi/UIView-MGBadgeView
This may help you.

Comment: I already added cutombadge. but my question is how to reload when change badge?

Comment: If you have use the MGBadgeview then you can use

    [btnAddToCart.badgeView setBadgeValue:[arrOrder count]];

Comment: but i us another third party dude. https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge

Comment: Inside that there is one method i think this one to set the text on badge
badge3.badgeText = @"4";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just Update my badge when I want to reload. For e.g. when I delete any product from cart I reinitialise the bar button item. Here, is my code:

> ```
>  NSMutableArray *arrProducts = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"CartList"];
>
> [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[arrProducts count] forKey:@"Badge"];
> [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
>
> UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
> UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shopping_cart.png"];
> [button setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
> // add badge to cart button.
> [CommonUtils AddBadge:button];
> [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AddToCartClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
> button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
>
> [btnAddtoCart initWithCustomView:button];
> ```

Comment: I would rather recommend you to maintain the global instance for your UIButton which you are adding to your UIBarButtonItem. The global instance of the UIButton can be then used to update the bagde. So creating the whole button altogether can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Check condition and show/hide badge accordingly.

First, you have to hide badge. When any item is selected check count of item selected is greater than 0 then show badge.

Every time any item selected show badge.

Every time any item deselected check if selected item == 0 then hide badge.